# Interaction between restartBrowserBetweenTests with onPrepare()

Tags: selenium, protractor

I want each of my tests to run on clean browser (Firefox) so i use `restartBrowserBetweenTests:true` option. Because i use non-Angular demo app, in `onPrepare()` function i use `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`. It's works fine, when i run a single spec, but when i run 2 specs, i have error.

`Angular could not be found on the page. If this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting for Angular.`

How can i solve this? And in addition, how `onPrepare` works in this case - every time when browser starts or one time before all specs?

Here is my conf.js

```
const screenshotReporter = require('./screenshotCustomReporter')

exports.config = {
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox'
    },

    restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,

    framework: 'jasmine',
    directConnect: true,

    baseUrl: URL,

    specs: ['path/**/*Spec.js'],

    // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
        includeStackTrace: true
    },

    onPrepare: () => {
        require("@babel/register");

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(screenshotReporter)
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)
    }
}
```

---

You can recreate this issue using the following simple project:

**conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',
    specs: ['./app.1.js', './app.2.js'],
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    restartBrowserBetweenTests:true,
    onPrepare:function(){
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    },
}
```

**app.1.js**

```
describe('second test', () => {
    it('should check is displayed successfully', () => {
        browser.driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
        browser.driver.sleep(5000);
        expect(element(by.linkText('Ask Question')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

**app.2.js**

```
describe('first test', () => {
    it('should check is displayed successfully', () => {
        browser.driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
        browser.driver.sleep(5000);
        expect(element(by.linkText('Ask Question')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnPrepare is defined for all settings need to be executed for suite. It means it 
is always one time operation irrespective of number of spec files.

One concept you need to understand is that whenever the new instance of
firefox browser is launched then WebdriverJs initialize the instance of webdriver.
and global object browser in protractor also gets initialized.

In your case First spec file start firefox browser, OnPrepare function is executed afterwards and 
default setting of protractor is overriden by WaitForAngularEnabled.But when you run second spec file,
again firefox browser is launched with fresh instance of webdriver and protractor browser which expect
angular application and in that case test case gets failed.

The solution for this problem is to use before function in spec file

```
describe('first test', () => {
      before(() => {
                     browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
       });

    it('should check is displayed successfully', () => {
        browser.driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
        browser.driver.sleep(5000);
        expect(element(by.linkText('Ask Question')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Note : If you are using restartBrowserBetweenTests: true then you will have to use **beforeEach()** function for waitForAngularEnabled because every time fresh instance of webdriver will be created.

Comment: Nice answer, I wasn't aware of this. You could also add the `beforeEach` in the `onPrepare` to save code: `onPrepare(): function(){ 
  beforeEach(function(){ 
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);  
  }
) }` That way it will be executed in all specs

Comment: @nitin-sahu thanks for explanation! Also small note: in Jasmine instead of `before` uses `beforeAll`. 
@DublinDev thanks for onPrepare tip and for providing example.